# javascript error - property can't be read from undefined - but it was checked for undefined

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting this error?  "candlestick.actions" is sometimes a jsonarray and sometimes it's a non-existant key under candlestick (when no actions occur that day), but the check on candlestick.actions should prevent this from happening - should it not?  In what circumstance can this happen?

I think the best way to describe this is with this image.  You can see the conditional that should prevent this from happening, followed by a return.  How could the candlestick.actions.length even be reached if candlestick.actions === undefined would have returned?

[image]

Here's the code.  This is at the tail end of my "DrawCandlestick" function. I was just about to say that Javascript is not multi-threaded and it doesn't appear to me that I change the array anywhere in this branch of code - yet an object becomes undefined, but then I realized that the array could be changing because of an event in primefaces.  This is an xhtml page that receives new graphs, so I probably have changed the array somehow indirectly when not supposed to...  Anyway, apologies for not posting the code on the first go, but I was trying to be very specific with my question.

```
if(candlestick.actions === undefined || !candlestick.actions || candlestick.actions === null ||
        candlestick.actions.length === undefined || !candlestick.actions.length)
    return;

for( var i = 0; i < candlestick.actions.length; i++) {

    var candlestick = candlestick.actions[i];

    if(candlestick.action === "BUY") {

        var leftOfArrow = centerX - this.candlestickColumnWidth / 2;
        var topOfArrow = lowY+1;
        var widthOfArrow = this.candlestickColumnWidth;
        var heightOfArrow = this.canvas.clientHeight * 0.05;
        this.drawArrowUp(this.canvasContext, leftOfArrow, topOfArrow, widthOfArrow, heightOfArrow, "blue", "black");
    }

    else if(candlestick.action === "SELL") {

        var leftOfArrow = centerX - this.candlestickColumnWidth / 2;
        var heightOfArrow = this.canvas.clientHeight * 0.05;
        var topOfArrow = highY-heightOfArrow-1;
        var widthOfArrow = this.candlestickColumnWidth;
        this.drawArrowDown(this.canvasContext, leftOfArrow, topOfArrow, widthOfArrow, heightOfArrow, "purple", "black");
    }
}
```

the drawArrowDown function is just a canvas painting method - and drawArrowUp is basically the same thing but with things moved around a bit to point up.

```
drawArrowDown(ctx, left, top, width, height, bkColor, borderColor) {

    var right = left+width;
    var bottom = top+height;
    var middle = left+(right-left)/2;

    ctx.beginPath();

    // top-middle peak, moving counter-clockwise around the arrow:
    ctx.moveTo(left, top);
    ctx.lineTo(middle, bottom);
    ctx.lineTo(right, top);

    // complete custom shape
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = bkColor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = borderColor;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Post all errors and code here as text as a [mcve]

Comment: Your `if` conditional will not be entered into if `candlestick.actions` is defined yet the `length` is equal to `0`. You have an empty array.

Comment: I do believe the entire code required, including the error, is best described by looking at a zoom-in of the image.  I should have made that clear.  I will edit the question to mention that.  Thanks!

Comment: Show the code. There is a chance that you are destroying `candlestick.actions` inside the loop but you are not showing it.

Comment: Hi Javier - that probably answers the question actually.  If that code should work, then it has to be that I'm modifying the array elsewhere in the process.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, the error says that length is a property of undefined.  If the array were empty, then length would be defined and length would be zero - but it's not zero - it's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destroying the `candlestick` object by defining it and assigning it a different value inside the loop.

```
var candlestick = candlestick.actions[i];
```

Change it for another name across the loop (not just the definition):

```
var candlestickAction = candlestick.actions[i];
```

Then:

```
if (candlestickAction.action === "BUY") {
```

And so on with other occurrences.

Note: Declaration with `var` affects the entire enclosing function, not just the loop block.

Comment: Wow- scope!  I sure took scope for granted.  Thanks so much!